# Why do I have to spread my object twice when copying state from my react object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, javascript-objects, spread

I have this object below, I want to test that when i perform an action to change the state of the `group` key in the state that it updates correctly. As you can see there are way more key value pairs in this object than just `group` so I would like to spread the `initialState` object and write my test changing only the `group` value.

Here is the initialState:

```
export const initialState = {
  testing: false,
  filters: {
    start: moment()
      .startOf("month")
      .format(),
    end: moment()
      .endOf("month")
      .format(),
    city: "",
    group: "daily"
  },
  locations: []
};
```

My unit test:

```
test("It performs the setGroup action correctly", () => {
    const active = "month";

    const action = setGroup(active);

    const state = reducer(
      {
        ...initialState,
        filters: {
          ...initialState.filters,
          group: "daily"
        }
      },
      action
    );

    expect(state).toEqual({
      ...initialState,
      filters: {
        ...initialState.filters,
        group: "month"
      }
    });
  });
```

This test works however I want to know why I have to spread the `initialstate` once, and then again within the filters object I have to spread the `initialState.filters` again just to manipulate the month.

In my head this should work fine :

```
const state = reducer(
      {
        ...initialState,
        filters: {
          group: "daily"
        }
      },
      action
    );
```

My question is why do I need to put the line `initialState.filters` to make this test viable. Please can someone help me understand? I have done research but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `...initialState.filters` you are spreading the `filters` object on `initialState`. You have to do this as you have just defined a new `filters` object in your reducer and so have to place in it the values you want to keep from the old version.

If this all seems a bit to verbose, then check out Immer, which allows you to have immutable objects with a bit more a traditional API

https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction

Comment: This helps me understand. So just to clarify, when I spread the `initialState` object the first time I am making a new copy of the object as a whole. Then I have to say something like from this new `initialState` I want to keep the filters object (`...initialState.filters`) and the `group` value within it.

Comment: Almost, you have do the second one as you redefined `filters` when you add or change a value to it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's spread operator is fairly dumb; it doesn't attempt to do any kind of smart merging like some libraries offer. When you add the `filters` prop JavaScript simply overwrites `initialState`'s spread `filters` definition.

You can think of your code sample as being roughly equivalent to

```
Object.assign(
  {},
  initialState,
  {
    filters: { ... }
  })
```